# Count from table in database sql

Tags: php, sql

How can i count a specific ward in a table in database sql. Example, i have a table and i want to count how many times repeated ward "hello", can you help me please)

Comment: How does your table look? I'd be able to provide you with a functioning query if I have a rough idea how the table looks.

Comment: @Thoby you can help me with any example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a target table ie `tbl_test` with a column i.e `my_column`, the query would look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_test WHERE my_column = 'hello';
```

Comment: Can i search with no specific column in the table?

Comment: For Ms Sql sever ,try this:  [link](http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question it should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Word), Country
FROM Customers
WHERE Word='hello'
GROUP BY Country;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: If you posted how your table looks I could write an example with your variables

Comment: Maybe its what i want, i will try it. Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

You can try select count(nameOfTheFieldWhenCanAppearHello)from table 
where nameOfTheFieldWhenCanAppearHello='Hello' 
group by nameOfTheFieldWhenCanAppearHello